# limit involving a matrix with growing dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, limits

Consider two sequence of real valued $m\times m$ matrices $W_m(n)$ and $\Omega_m(n)$ such that ${\Omega_m(n)} {\rightarrow} {\Omega_m}$ and ${W_m(n)} {\rightarrow} {\Omega_m}^{-1}$ where $n {\rightarrow} \infty$ and ${\Omega_m}^{-1}$ for any natural number $m$ exists. What can we say about the following limit(is it always equal to one):

$(1/m)Trace[({W_m(n)} {\Omega_m(n)}]$ where $m{\rightarrow}n {\rightarrow} \infty$

Comment: What does "$W_m(n)\to \Omega_m(n)^{-1}$" mean?  What is $\Omega_m(n)$?

Comment: @ Eric Wofsey, I edited the question, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You can't say much.  For instance, it might be the case that $\Omega_m(m)=W_m(m)=0$ for all $m$ and $\Omega_m(n)=W_m(n)$ is the identity whenever $m\neq n$, and so for any $N$, there exist $m,n>N$ such that $(1/m)\operatorname{Trace}[({W_m(n)} {\Omega_m(n)}]=0$ (namely, take any $m=n>N$).  The most you can say is that *if* the limit $\lim_{(m,n)\to(\infty,\infty)}(1/m)\operatorname{Trace}[({W_m(n)} {\Omega_m(n)}]$ exists, then it must be $1$.  To see this, note that for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $m$, there exist arbitrarily large $n$ such that $|(1/m)\operatorname{Trace}[({W_m(n)} {\Omega_m(n)}]-1|<\epsilon$ since ${W_m(n)} {\Omega_m(n)}$ converges to the identity matrix as $n\to\infty$.  In particular, for any $N$, there exist $m,n>N$ such that $|(1/m)\operatorname{Trace}[({W_m(n)} {\Omega_m(n)}]-1|<\epsilon$.